# Parse nested absolute values

Tags: code-golf, parsing

*The absolute value of a number \$x\$ is normally written as \$|x|\$. The left and right side of the absolute value uses the same symbol, so it is not immediately obvious how to parse nested absolute values e.g. \$||1-2|+|3-|4-5|||\$*

Your goal is to parse such an expression containing nested absolute values:

The expression will be given as a string of characters. 
For simplicity the expression will only contain single-digit numbers (or letters if that is easier in your language),
the operators `+` and `-` (you can use any two distinct characters to represent these operations), and the symbol `|` for the left and right side of an absolute value. 
You do *not* need to handle the case where a number is directly adjacent to an absolute value (e.g. `2|3|` or `|2|3`)

Your output should be the same expression in a form that allows you to determine how the absolute values are bracketed.

The output has to satisfy the following rules:

- The expression within an absolute value must not end with an operator ( `+` or `-` )
- The expression within an absolute value cannot be empty
- Each `|` has to be part of exactly one absolute value

You may assume there is a valid way to parse the given input.

Examples:

```
|2|                ->  (2)
|2|+|3|            ->  (2)+(3)
||2||              ->  ((2))
||2|-|3||          ->  ((2)-(3))
|-|-2+3||          ->  (-(-2+3))
|-|-2+3|+|4|-5|    ->  (-(-2+3)+(4)-5)
|-|-2+|-3|+4|-5|   ->  (-(-2+(-3)+4)-5)
||1-2|+|3-|4-5|||  ->  ((1-2)+(3-(4-5)))
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution wins.

## Optional additional requirement:

Also support expressions that allow a number direct before or after a bracket.
If the result is not unique, you may return any valid solution.

test-cases (for optional requirement):

```
|2|3|4|  -> (2(3)4)
|2|3|4|  -> (2)3(4)
||3|4|   -> ((3)4)
|2|3-|4| -> (2)3-(4)
|1+|2|3| -> (1+(2)3)
|1+2|3|| -> (1+2(3))
```

Comment: *The expression within a absolute value must not end with an operator*. Do you have a testcase in mind where this could be a problem? I have a solution which doesn't check for this, but I'm having a hard time finding an example where this is actually an issue

Comment: @ovs one possible example would be parsing the second test case as `(2(+)3)`

Comment: Would `|1+2|3||` be a valid test case for the optional requirement?

Comment: (Your optional requirement test cases seem to test for a number after a bracket, not before.)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>s>(s=s.replace(/\|(.*?[\d)])\|/,"($1)"))?f(s):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBLDoJADIDhvacgxEXrWAivjQlwEHFBeBgNAcIYV707FqMCArPt/zUzc0@fqc66W/ugusmLvi9DHUY6Ah1qqyvaKs0KsBMG6xCfkxwvmLB9NGHvoIkYl6DxpPusqXVTFVbVXKEEk102jdlBNGzbMMDF3bJV7E37sVXgLXsB8@3fXsBqTbJ@FJOaZP1SEJOr1gTBMNgWin2mYHB/QoGPFGw4JpEfOHNAItchO/T@NWJfnFz19ygZDL9GIANE7F8)

#### Method

At each iteration, we look for the first substring consisting of:

- `\|` a leading pipe
- `.*?` the shortest possible string
- `[\d)]` either a digit or a closing parenthesis
- `\|` a trailing pipe

and replace the pipes with `(` and `)` respectively.

If a replacement occurs, the new string is *less than* the original string in lexicographical order, because the leading pipe is turned into an opening parenthesis. Hence the test `s > (s = s.replace(...))` which triggers a recursive call if true.

**NB**: A safer way would be to use `[^|]*` instead of `.*?`. If you find a test case where `.*?` fails, please let me know.

Comment: The pattern works wonderfully with JavaScript regexes, but cannot make it work the same way with [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), possibly because of differences in empty string matching.

Comment: `[^|]*` wouldn't need a `?`, would it?

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>22</s> 16 bytes

```
T`|`)`\d\|+
\|
(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@xDsIwDET3fEVGW9ENtOnKVzBmSCUYWBgQ4/17uFAqUFuP997J9vP2uj/m1i6V1Wu5FqZQGKw1DoybwTlGGzwIJY48QMlGYXEeNMUXCJW5h1BZAogh7QVYj/@ExExM3ArJsmNaNULi6v00g8SvxxM@/4BZWt@7HKS4/wNT7O5v) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`|`)`\d\|+
```

Replace all `|`s that appear after digits with `)`s.

```
\|
(
```

Replace the remaining `|`s with `(`s.

Comment: I think you can split this up into two separate replace to save a byte: [TIO](https://tio.run/##bY8xDsIwEAR7v8IFxZ2sLeI4LR8hSCBBQUOBKPfvZk0SgZJcY2lnVud73d@P57XWdLHTePOzjwyHzoMeq5WZcTU4xmjZg1Bizx2UrBcW505TfIJQmVsIlSWAyGkrwFr8JyQWYuBaSFYcw6IREhfvpxkkzh47fO8Bi7S2d/qQ4nYPTLG7fwA)

Comment: @ovs I took your idea to its logical conclusion...

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>27</s> 22 bytes

Based on Arnauld's answer, but without regex.

```
{`c$(84-0=\"0|"'x)!'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pOSFbRsDDRNbCNUTKoUVKv0FRUr6jl4kpTqjGqUYJQ2jXGyEztGhMIF8iHM3SBEhCObo2ukTYaB6RF1xRJqEYXKIgQqzHUBZutW2MCFALqBQD/sCu7)

Any closing parenthesis in the output directly follows a digit or another closing parenthesis, and none of the opening ones do. This means we can replace all consecutive `|`'s following a digit by closing parentheses. The remaining `|`'s are replaced by opening ones.

---

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 36 bytes

My first idea, tests all ways of replacing `|` with parentheses using try/eval.

```
{c@*<.[.:;;`]','c:+`c$(83+!2&x)!''x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pOdtCy0YvWs7K2TohV11FPttJOSFbRsDDWVjRSq9BUVFevqOXiSlOqMapRglDaNcbITO0aEwgXyIczdIESEI5uja6RNhoHpEXXFEmoRhcoiBCrMdQFm61bYwIUAuoFAAolLuc=)

It is not very easy to show this is correct, as `(1+)` is a valid expression in K. However after toying around with this for quite some time, I'm convinced that you can't construct a valid input where this actually becomes a problem

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＦＳ≡ι|§)(‹ψ0«ι≔ιψ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvLCoMwEEXX@hVDVjPUQJ8bu3IpdFHoF4QYNSCxJLGtdPz2NNDlPedcPSqvZzWl1M8esHXPJT6it25AIghvG/UIaAm@pVbBgGBRwz37iE1sXWc@KAhFBTcTAq4ViL0gomvZmV4tU6zzsfj3NtOiCcEODm0Fa55buaXEfJBH3vFJ8llemDnJ1/QD) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ≡ι
```

Loop over the input characters.

```
|§)(‹ψ0
```

If the current characters is a `|` then output a `)` or `(` depending on whether the last non-`|` was less than `0`.

```
«ι≔ιψ
```

Otherwise output the character and save it as the last non-`|`.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(d=/./g,c=>c>{}?++d?')':'(':d=c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBLDoJADIDhvacgbmgzFiKPDcnAWcjwiIYAAePGenYsRgUEZtv/a2bmmt7T3nSX9kZ1k@VDoYdex73T5W2Vmhwy7TpueTI6NvHjmSiVJTbakQ12lGmDg2nqvqlyp2pKKODIHh@txUG0XNeywMPDulXsz/upVeCvewHL7d9ewGZNsn4Ss5pk/VoQk6e2BME42BeKA6ZwdH9CQYAU7jgmkR@4cEAityGf6f1rxIE4uervUTIYf41ABog4vAA)

Look last non-pipe character before each pipe. Converting pipe to `)` only when last non-pipe is a digit, and converting to `(` otherwise. Does not work with the optional additional requirement.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ε'|Qižu®dèëy©
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267303/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

Outputs as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9vc2FiaWX//861J3xRacW@dcKuZMOow6t5wqn//3x8MS0yfCt8My18NC01fHx8) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaWhxqGVMf/PbVWvCcw8uq/00LqUwysOr648tPJ/ba2LvZeSgpXC4f1KOv@jlWqMapR0QKR2jTGYBWTCaF2gEJitW6NrpI3K1q4xqdE1RYjU6ALF4EI1hrpgE3VrTIAiQI2x/3V18/J1cxKrKgE).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε           # Map over the characters of the (implicit) input:
 '|Qi      '#  If the current character is a "|":
     žu     #   Push builtin string "()<>[]{}"
       ®    #   Push variable `®` (which is -1 by default)
        d   #   Check whether it's a non-negative (>=0) number
         è  #   Use that check (0 or 1) to (0-based) index into string "()<>[]{}"
    ë       #  Else:
     y      #   Simply push the current character
      ©     #   And store it in variable `®` (without popping)
            # (after which the mapped list of characters is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 26 bytes

```
gkx"(/d(/|{)_)+|/|{(_|.)+"
```

This solution uses a "regex" to replace each of the `|`s with either `(` or `)`.

A closing paren must be preceded by a valid statement, and valid statements can only end in either digits, or a closing paren. Meanwhile a open paren can never come after a digit or a closing paren, so this classification is complete.

We translate these rules to the "regex":

```
(                  )+  -- at least once
 /d                    -- a digit
   (     )+            -- at least one of
    /|                 -- a |
      {)_              -- replaced with )
           |           -- or
            /|         -- a |
              {(_      -- replaced with (
                 |     -- or 
                  .    -- any character
```

## Without "regex", 36 bytes

```
gkY$dgS<>sO(hh"|"")")++hh"|""("++hdS
```

This is the same idea as the algorithm above, but implemented using parser combinators.

This is considerably longer, as parser combinators tend to be at a disadvantage to the "regex" when it comes to challenges involving the specific behavior of specific characters.

### 36 bytes

```
rA"|""("<gkY(dgS<>sO(hh"|"")")++hdS)
```

This is another solution which is also the same length, but which uses a mix of parser and non-parser functions.

## Reflection

Although these solutions don't exactly feel good, there is remarkably little I see in the way of improvement.

### Regex

There's very little that can be done to improve the "regex" based solution. I have no plans to change the syntax of "regex" in the near future, and to be honest I don't even know what I would do.

- The only thing I can think of is to make a combined version of `gkx` and `gkY`. This would pull the `(...)+` out and save 3 bytes.

### Non-regex

I have more thoughts here, but even with all my suggestions this doesn't come close to catching up with the regex.

- The time has probably come for a combined version of `<>` and `sO`.
- `hh"|"")"` is annoyingly long. There are two ways to solve this:

  - Simplest is that like other characters we could just add a shortcut to `hh"|"`. Of course next time we are going to want to do something like `hh"@""*"` and this will have been completely useless, but if we keep adding these eventually we will get there.
  - A more principled solution would be to implement something like `xx` but taking a single string argument and unconsing it to get two arguments. e.g. `xxh(x:xs)=xx x xs`. This would allow it to be `xxh"|)"` which saves only a byte.