# Parse nested absolute values 2

Tags: code-golf, parsing

**Looking at
[Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267297/parse-nested-absolute-values-2/267300#267300), it seems like this version is not really more difficult than the other version, so I made it an optional requirement of the other challenge**

*The absolute value of a number \$x\$ is normally written as \$|x|\$. The left and right side of the absolute value uses the same symbol, so it is not immediately obvious how to parse nested absolute values e.g. \$||1-2|+|3-|4-5|||\$*

Your goal is to parse such an expression containing nested absolute values:

The expression will be given as a string of characters.
For simplicity the expression will only contain single digit numbers (or letters if that is easier in your language),
the operators `+` and `-` (you can use any two distinct characters to represent these operations) and the symbol `|` for the left and right side of a absolute value.
To make the challenger not too easy, it is allowed for numbers to be directly adjacent to absolute values so (`2|3|` and `|2|3` both are valid expressions). See the [first version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267296/parse-nested-absolute-values) if you do not want to handle that case

Your output should be the same expression in a form that allows to determine how the absolute values are bracketed.

The output has to satisfy the following rules:

- The expression within a absolute value must not end with an operator ( `+` or `-` )
- The expression within a absolute value cannot be empty
- Each `|` has to be part of exactly one absolute value

You may assume there is a valid way to parse the given input. If there is more than one way to parse the expression you can choose any valid solution.

Examples (all possible outputs):

```
|2|                ->  (2)
|2|+|3|            ->  (2)+(3)
|2|3|-4|           ->  (2)3(-4)    
|2|3|-4|           ->  (2(3)-4)
|2|3-|4|           ->  (2)3-(4)
||2||              ->  ((2))
||2|-|3||          ->  ((2)-(3))
|-|-2+3||          ->  (-(-2+3))
|-|-2+3|+|4|-5|    ->  (-(-2+3)+(4)-5)
|-|-2+|-3|+4|-5|   ->  (-(-2+(-3)+4)-5)
||1-2|+|3-|4-5|||  ->  ((1-2)+(3-(4-5)))
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution wins.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) [parsing](/questions/tagged/parsing)

Comment: Please let me know if you need me to delete my CW answer in order to delete the post (I don't know if that's required).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

I believe [my answer to the other version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267298/58563) also works for this one... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```javascript
f=s=>s>(s=s.replace(/\|(.*?[\d)])\|/,"($1)"))?f(s):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddFNDoIwEAXgvacgxMWMdSDyszFBDyIuCILRECDUuJq749SogJQu2/elfdN79sx03t3aB9XNpej7MtHJQR9AJ9rrirbK8gL8lMHbHE/pBc@Ysr91Yb1DF/FYgsa97vOm1k1VeFVzhRJcDth1JgvR8X3HgQBX86zicJwfsgpCWz5kikZgyIdAEZotGyJeQATR/BYR0w5fIMKaJnnWIEZpkhJzQUyBsgkCc7AslNSg2Lg/oaQGxQuOSeQHThyQSDvkHb3/RgYnTp76KyUH5m9kcOIQ@xc)